# how to parse json data with jquery with multiple

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, function

My sample Json

```
[  { "id":"Name1", "fname":"Name1","lname":"Test","Teaser":"location1, location2" },
   { "id":"Name2", "fname":"Name2", "lname":"abcd", "Teaser":"location3, location4" },
   { "id":"Name3", "fname":"Name3", "lname":"yxzk","Teaser":"location2, location4"},
   { "id":"Name4", "fname":"Name4", "lname":"zxya", "Teaser":"location3"}
]
```

Below code reads the json data and selects all unique Teaser. We are able to get the unique teaser form Json.

```
    var locarr = [];
    var loc = [];
    var jsonString = "["
    var test = [];
    var loca = []
    var map = new Object(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            $(result).each(function(index, listItem) {
                loc = $.trim(result[index].Teaser).split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++)
                    locarr.push($.trim(loc[i]));
            });

            test = $.unique(locarr);

        $(result).each(function(index2, listItem2) 
        {
            var docname = result[index2].fname;
            var teaser = result[index2].Teaser;
            var locar = [];
            locar = result[index2].Teaser.split(",");               
             testfunc(docname,teaser);                         
        });
        //console.log(map); 
    }
});
```

Here is my new function to read the data

```
    var val = 0;
    function testfunc(doc,teas){
            //console.log(map);
            for(var j=0;j<test.length;j++){
                if(teas.indexOf(test[j])> -1){                    
                    map[test[j]] = doc+"j";                       
                }
                val++;
            }                       
    }
```

What i want is based on unique Teaser need to add the fname under the Teaser. my expectation is like below. Is it possible get data from the Json. Any help.

```
location1
Name1

location2
Name1
Name3

location3
Name2
Name4

location4
Name2
Name3
```

Comment: You want the result as new js collection, html lists.. or what?

Comment: should be in html list

Comment: You mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/uat1dpuj/

Comment: yes, thank you very much, we are expecting same output